# Configure paypal sandbox for local networks

Tags: proxy, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, reverse-proxy, nat

Is there a way to configure a Paypal sandbox IPN for local networks? Since I am testing it on my personal computer I cannot provide a static IP.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal delivers IPNs to a URL that you provide. It has to be reachable by PayPal.

The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree that paypal sends IPNs to URLs that are reachable. What I intend to ask is that, do we have any solution for me to test my code on sandbox, may be by using a proxy server or making some tweeks in the NAT.

Comment: Then I suggest you ask what you intended to ask in your question, instead of what you did ask, which was about how to configure the Paypal sandbox IPN.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to work with paypal sandbox on local networks.

Install ngrok. This creates a public address for your local network so that it can be accessible from outside networks. You can use the ipaddress generated by it to test ipn.